# How do I enable/disable a textbox when a radio button is clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a radio button with a textbox.  How do I enable/disable the textbox using the onclick event of a radio button?  That is, if the radio button is selected then the textbox should be enabled or else disabled.

Here is my code below:

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="type" id="type1">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" onChange="javascript:enableField();"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="type" id="type1" onclick="toggleTextbox(this);" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>" id="name1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleTextbox(rdo) {
    document.getElementById("name1").disabled = !rdo.checked;
}
</script>
```